# Android - getting the current rotation of a matrix

Tags: java, android, matrix

I need to be able to set the rotation of a matrix rather than add to it. I believe the only way to set the rotation is to know the current rotation of the matrix.

Note: `matrix.setRotate()` will not do, because the matrix needs to retain its information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is call `getValues` and cache the values. Later when you want them back just call `setValues` on the matrix.

### Update

The rotation matrix and transform matrix relation well explained [here](http://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/)

Comment: getValue returns a float array, which index is the rotation?

Comment: I have marked as the accepted answer because you gave me a way to find the rotation. Although I ended up going with a simpler solution. My solution was to keep track of the current rotation myself rather than finding it through the matrix. I feel this way is both easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 9):

```
float[] v = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(v);
// translation is simple
float tx = v[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
float ty = v[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

// calculate real scale
float scalex = v[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
float skewy = v[Matrix.MSKEW_Y];
float rScale = (float) Math.sqrt(scalex * scalex + skewy * skewy);

// calculate the degree of rotation
float rAngle = Math.round(Math.atan2(v[Matrix.MSKEW_X], v[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI));
```

from here 
http://judepereira.com/blog/calculate-the-real-scale-factor-and-the-angle-of-rotation-from-an-android-matrix/

Comment: i calculated the rotation using float rAngle = Math.round(Math.atan2(v[Matrix.MSKEW_X], v[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI)); need to multiply with -1 to get the correcct value . why is tha happen?

Comment: I'll second @VV's comment; rotation was in wrong direction without negating.

Comment: @Project : -ve was a mistake from my side, the order of matrix was different. but still i need to apply setPivotX(0);
             setPivotY(0); to get exact position after rotation why is that

Comment: get degree rotation went wrong when scaleX and scaleY have different values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I can't help you with the integration (I've done this in Flash only), but it sounds like you should try to do your matrix calculations yourself, which is best done using "quaternions", which makes adding rotations pretty trivial. See http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/32class/Quaternion.java.html for an example Java implementation. You would want to create a second quaternion matrix that describes your change in rotation and add (in this case, `plus`) it to your current matrix.