# Get the rotate value from matrix in android?

Tags: android, matrix, rotation

How to the rotate value from a translated/scaled/rotated matrix?

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(...);
matrix.postTranslate(...);
matrix.postRotate(...);
...
```

Now I don't know what the `rotate` it was, but I need to get it. How to do this?

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/7291213/739270

Comment: Decomposing a matrix into translation, scaling, and rotation is explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no defined way to extract the rotation information (I'll assume you are looking for the number of degrees). The best you can do is extract the matrix values using `getValues` and use a conversion formula (something like is discussed towards the bottom of [this](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/) page) to try and figure out the angle.

Comment: That page is very useful, I get it now.

Answer (score 30):

```
float[] v = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(v);
// translation is simple
float tx = v[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
float ty = v[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

// calculate real scale
float scalex = v[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
float skewy = v[Matrix.MSKEW_Y];
float rScale = (float) Math.sqrt(scalex * scalex + skewy * skewy);

// calculate the degree of rotation
float rAngle = Math.round(Math.atan2(v[Matrix.MSKEW_X], v[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI));
```

from here
http://judepereira.com/blog/calculate-the-real-scale-factor-and-the-angle-of-rotation-from-an-android-matrix/

Comment: Much better than the marked answer. Thanks! It works.

Comment: i calculated the rotation using float rAngle = Math.round(Math.atan2(v[Matrix.MSKEW_X], v[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI)); need to multiply with -1 to get the correcct value . why is tha happen?

Comment: what is the "values" in this line....float scalex = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]; is it meant to be "v"?

Comment: i am getting wrong scale factor. this scale factor reduces Image size after scale. is there any other way to get scale factor?

Comment: the calculated degree is not perfect when scaleX and scaleY have different values.

Answer (score 8):

I can't enter equation here, so I make a picture of how to solve your problem. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: is there any way to set rotation to matrix, because when i apply rotation it will resets whole matrix,let me show you:
before:
`{[0.38719338, -0.035239104, 9.199848]
[0.035239104, 0.38719338, -24.01611]
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`
after adding rotation `matrix.setRotate(0);` matrix values will be like:
`{[1.0, -0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to previous answers, here is the Kotlin extension you need. 
It returns the rotation angle value of this matrix

```
fun Matrix.getRotationAngle() = FloatArray(9)
    .apply { getValues(this) }
    .let { -round(atan2(it[MSKEW_X], it[MSCALE_X]) * (180 / PI)).toFloat() }
```

Just need to call it on your matrix. Note that your matrix values won't be changed.

```
val angleInDegree = yourMatrix.getRotationAngle()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more convenient implementation of @Evansgelist's answer for Kotlin users:

```kotlin
val Matrix.rotation: Float
    get() {
        return atan2(
            values()[Matrix.MSKEW_X],
            values()[Matrix.MSCALE_X],
        ) * (180f / Math.PI.toFloat())
    }

val Matrix.scale: Float
    get() {
        return sqrt(
        values()[Matrix.MSCALE_X].pow(2) +
            values()[Matrix.MSKEW_Y].pow(2)
        )
    }

val Matrix.translationX: Float
    get() { return values()[Matrix.MTRANS_X] }

val Matrix.translationY: Float
    get() { return values()[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] }
```

Note that every call to `values` allocates a new `FloatArray`.