# Getting The current Rotation of a Matrix - using a library?

Tags: java, android, matrix, rotation

Firstly lets say I have forgotten most of my maths long ago. I do not need to understand it in depth. The question was asked and answered (see links) but I do not want to derive my own function, is there an existing one ? The image below show a Matrix which I have rotated 45 degrees. Is there a **[image: simple]** way I could plug in the 0.707 numbers and get 45 back ? At the moment I am keeping track of the rotation on my own (simple solution), but I would prefer a function to derive back the 45 degrees

[question 7291053](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291053/android-getting-the-current-rotation-of-a-matrix)

[Matrix Rotation](http://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/)

Comment: try to compute sin(45)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the angles of each axis x,y,and z

```
[0][1][2]
[3][4][5]
[6][7][8]


double x = Math.atan2([7], [8]);
double y = Math.atan2(-[6],Math.sqrt((Math.pow([7],2)+Math.pow([8],2)));
double z = Math.atan2([0], [3]);
```

then multiply the one you choose by 180/PI

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer. I will mark it as the correct one because it is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

The function is called "arcus sinus" or `arcsin(x)`. For `arcsin(0.707107) = 45` with a bit of rounding error.

In Java Math library you must additionally translate the result from RAD to DEG like this:
`Math.asin(0.707) * 180d / Math.PI`

Note that you get back something between -90° and +90° as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#asin%28double%29).

If you want to know which axis you actually rotate and on which part (lower, upper) of the circle you are, then you must take a look at all 9 values. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) how the matrices look like for each axis.

Comment: Thank You arcsin(0.707107) in degress gives 45.0000177 degrees

Comment: you can use atan2() for x,y,or z, angles also

Comment: The whole paragraph in Wikipedia link about determining the axis is somewhat cryptic still.

Comment: Sorry that I had to chose the other answer both are correct but I thought the other would be more helpful to anyone finding this.