# Android Java - set angle with postRotate

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

Basically I need to be able to set an image's angle to a degree using postRotate.  It seems setRotate does this job perfectly but it also rewrites the matrix... How can I fix this?

Edit:

pskink saves the day, and here's a better version of my question [Android - getting the current rotation of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291053/android-getting-the-current-rotation-of-a-matrix/7291213#7291213)

Comment: after each postRotate update mAngle field so when you want to rotate to the fixed angle you could call postRotate(finalAngle - mAngle)

Comment: hey, its you again! thank you pskink, you're very insightful. i keep thinking there would be a predefined value or answer, but it's just math.

Comment: Thanks for the help pskink :) I got it working thanks to your help throughout my questions! I hope you understand you're a big help and I wouldn't hesitate to help you if you need anything!

Comment: no prob,  so finally what did you do?

Comment: I ended up setting the X and Y of the matrix to variables where each time I postTranslate(postx, posty), I would store them as X+=postx,Y+=posty and the rotation works as you said with the center pivots X+getWidth()/2,Y+getHeight()/2.  The confusing part was learning what pre,set,post did since the android descriptions were pretty obscure